# Vue optimization for large dropdowns on list of items

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I am experiencing some performance issues in Vue after migrating from an old angularjs app.
The page displays a list of available reports with a settings button alongside each report.
Likewise each report has among other things a property called worksheet which indicates the name of the worksheet driving this report.
So for example something like this

```
<div class="list" v-for="(report,repidx) in filteredReports" v-show="hideDemo.indexOf(report.Name) == -1">
<h2>{{report.Name}}</h2><button @click="report.showsettings=true">Settings</button>
<div v-show="report.showsettings">
<select name="worksheet" v-model="report.worksheet">
   <option v-for="worksheet in allworksheets">{{worksheet.Name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

When clicking on the settings button a dropdown list is exposed which indicates all the available worksheets that could be assigned to the selected report

"allworksheets" is an array of objects which might contain a 1000 worksheets.
Having it populated on the DOM (using v-for) for each report in the list does not seem efficient and causes tremendous performance issues on page loading and also during operations eg clicking on Settings button. (Surprisingly this worked perfectly fine in angularjs).

I tried switching to using a computed property but that also didnt help.

It gets even more complicated because the angular approach also had an additional option group which displayed SIMILAR worksheets to the currently selected one. For eg something like this

```
 <select name="worksheet" v-model="report.worksheet">
       <optgroup label="similarworksheets">
       <option v-for="sm in similarworksheets(report.worksheet)">{{sm.Name}}</option>
</optgroup>
       <optgroup label="allworksheets">
       <option v-for="worksheet in allworksheets">{{worksheet.Name}}</option>
</optgroup>
    </select>
```

In this case "similarworksheets" is a method that accepts the report.worksheet as a parameter and returns a filtered version of allworksheets, showing only SIMILAR worksheets. This obviously makes performance even worse!

Can someone suggest a better way to approach this given the fact that I need to stick to this structure - more or less - ie a dropdown list available for each selected report.
Thanks

Comment: please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130916/improve-performance-loop-items-vue-js/69134418#69134418

Comment: I was about to report some progress that's a little different to the above link. When using v-show everything is still rendered but just hidden. I found by correctly applying v-if the performance is improved significantly and working quite well. Specifically a v-if="report.ss" on the select element.